# Has controller action specific layouts changed in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just upgraded to Rails 4.1.

I previously had the following in a controller action, which worked perfectly.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render html: @user, layout: "fullscreen" }
end
```

This is not working in Rails 4.1, and the page simply renders the object `#<User:0x007fb087429a70>`

Edit the controller as follows fixes this error.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
```

What is the correct way to set the layout in Rails 4.1. I'm having trouble finding this in the docs.

Comment: Are you sure `render html: @user` worked for a Rails version lower than v4.1? Because `html` option was added in `render` method in Rails version 4.1.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I understood what exactly is happening. Read my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`html` option was added in `render` method in Rails version `4.1`. See the issue listed **[here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12374)**

When you tried

```
def action_name
## ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render html: @user, layout: "fullscreen" }
  end
end
```

in a `Rails` version prior to `v4.1`, what really happened was `render` ignored the `html` option, picked up the `layout` and went ahead to look for a view named `action_name.html.***`(where `***` refers to template handler like `erb`, `haml`, etc). It found the view and rendered it. If the view didn't exist then you would have received a `Missing template error`

And when you use the same code in `Rails 4.1`, as the `html` option is allowed in `render` method it will definitely be processed. Now, first you need to understand what the `html` option actually does:

> You can send a HTML string back to the browser by using the :html
>   option to render:
>
> ```
>  render html: "<strong>Not Found</strong>".html_safe
> ```

You use this **when you don't want to write an html file for your action** and **wish to simply render a HTML string.**

Which is the reason when this particular action is called you now see an html page with  object `#<User:0x007fb087429a70>` because you passed the value to `html` option as `@user`.

> *Edit the controller as follows fixes this error.*

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
```

Firstly, it was not an error. You misinterpreted what `html` option does. I am pretty sure you do have a view corresponding to your action which is what you expected to be rendered. The above code does that for you.

**I suppose you simply wish to specify `layout` for your view. All you need to do is:**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render layout: "fullscreen" }
end
```

Comment: thank you! that fixed it. Can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks!